# How to Change the Logo of an ActionBarDrawerToggle from android.support.v7?

Tags: android

I am setting the toggle for a Navigation Drawer in the `MainActivity` `OnCreate` Method. The android training guide on the [subject](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) has not been updated and still uses the v4 Constrcutor where you can set the logo:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                )
```

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Allow opening of Navigation drawer from Actionbar
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        //Set the logo of the toolbar
        //TODO: Set the logo

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                //R.drawable.ic_drawer,//R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* action var icon to replace up caret (icon pack) */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ){

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

What I get:

[image: Fail Hamburger]

What I would like is The ic_drawer then the Logo then the title.

Comment: You need to add the Toolbar..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```